# Example program WSTP Mathematica 10.3

Tags: interoperability, mathlink-or-wstp

I am writing a Fortran program and I want to use *Mathematica* functions form within. I know that a C wrapper should be written first, but I do not know how to proceed further. Basically I want to call somethign like this

```
FindRoot[x - A*PolyLog[3/2, B*Exp[-t*x]], {x, 0.0}]
```

for real numbers $A$, $B$, $t$. How to write a C program that would call the above function with given $A$, $B$, $t$ and return value of $x$ (possibly complex)? I have the latest *Mathematica* 10.3 running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I recommend reading through section 2 of [this document](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf) first and implementing a C version before you embark on the Fortran one.